# При попытке использовать php-cgi в с++ приложении выдает ошибку ("The PHP CGI cannot be accessed directly")

Tags: php, c++, http, cgi, http-server

Пишу свой сервер на с++, пытаюсь запустить php скрипт с помощью php - cgi.
Если скрипт простой, и ничего не принимает(следовательно не нужно устанавливать необходимые переменные окружения и передавать тело запроса в stdin), то все работает. Но когда я выставляю переменную EQUEST_METHOD, мне выдает вот такое сообщение

---

**Security Alert!** The PHP CGI cannot be accessed directly.

This PHP CGI binary was compiled with force-cgi-redirect enabled.  This
means that a page will only be served up if the REDIRECT_STATUS CGI variable is
set, e.g. via an Apache Action directive.

For more information as to *why* this behaviour exists, see the [manual page for CGI security](http://php.net/security.cgi-bin).

For more information about changing this behaviour or re-enabling this webserver,
consult the installation file that came with this distribution, or visit 
[the manual page](http://php.net/install.windows).

---

Как это исправить? ЧТо нужно выставить в переменной REDIRECT_STATUS?

вот код, класс conepipe является оберткой для fork, pipe, exec и тд.. Иными словами устанавливает двунаправленный pipe между процессами и позволяет общаться через stdin и stdout с помощью перегруженных операторов воода/выода.

```
int main()
{
    setenv("SCRIPT_FILENAME", "/home/anton/Cone_SERVER/serverFILES/test.php", 1);
    setenv("REQUEST_METHOD", "POST", 1);
    conepipe a("php-cgi");
    string msg = "first=5&operation=+&second=10&submit=Submit";
    string buf;
    a << msg;
    a >> buf;
    std::cout <<buf;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте 200 установить для REDIRECT_STATUS.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh, пробовал, это не работает